# Django NameError: name 'views' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am working through [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/rapid-website-deployment-with-django-heroku-new-relic--cms-21543) on rapid site development with `Django.`

I have followed it exactly (as far as I can see), but get the following error when I try to view the index page:

```
NameError at /name 'views' is not defined
Exception location: \tuts\urls.py in <module>, line 12
```

Here's *`urls.py`*:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Here's *`views.py`*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    items = Item.objects.order_by("-publish_date")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request,'portfolio/index.html', {"items": items, "year": now.year})
```

And here's *`models.py`*:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    publish_date = models.DateField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    url = models.URLField()
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I also have a basic `index.html` template in place. From looking around I think I need to import my view somewhere.

But I'm completely new to Django so I have no clue. Any ideas?

Comment: Always follow the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/). Not only is it guaranteed to work, it is also updated to reflect the current version of django.

Answer (score 35):

The error line is

```
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    #----------^
```

Here `views` is not defined, hence the error. You need to import it from your app.

in urls.py add line

```
from <your_app> import views
# replace <your_app> with your application name.
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. But now I get a new error:
name 'Item' is not defined
Exception Location: tuts\portfolio\views.py in index, line 5  I guess I need to import `Item`, but again where and how?

Comment: I think you can have a look to the Python doc about modules and import  [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: @user3181236 these are very trivial mistakes. In any python/django script you cannot use external things without importing them . So from <your_app>.models import Item

Answer (score 1):

```
from .views import index
```

- here we have to import views model classes on urls model so above sentence import your view model class on urls model.

add this code in urls.py

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rest_framework in django then import:

```
from rest_framework import views
```